# Jackson Mapper serialize empty object instead of null

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

Say I have classes Foo

```
public class Foo {
    private Bar bar;
}
```

and Bar

```
public class Bar {
    private String fizz;
    private String bang;
}
```

*EDIT*: For clarification I do not own `Foo` and `Bar` and cannot alter these classes.

If I want to serialize an empty object of type Foo, it's member, which is of type Bar, will be returned as null.

```
String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new Foo()); // "{"bar" : null}"
```

Is there any way I can get the object mapper to serialize an empty Bar object without having to instantiate a new instance of Bar and then adding it to a new instance of Foo?

```
String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new Foo()) // "{bar": {"fizz" : null, "bang" : null } }"
```

Comment: Why don't you just initialize a `Bar` object where `bar` is declared?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to clarify this, I do not own Foo and Bar and cannot change them.

Answer (score 9):

I was also required to produce such a structure for legacy client compatibility, here is my solution (depends on Spring Boot since uses @JsonComponent annotation)

Create "special object" that will be treated as empty

```
public class EmptyObject {
}
```

Create property in your model

```
@JsonProperty("data")
private EmptyObject data = new EmptyObject();

public EmptyObject getData() {
    return data;
}
```

Create serializer that will process empty object above

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer;
import com.sevensenders.datahub.api.service.response.model.EmptyObject;
import org.springframework.boot.jackson.JsonComponent;

import java.io.IOException;

@JsonComponent
public class EmptyObjectSerializer extends StdSerializer<EmptyObject> {

    public EmptyObjectSerializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public EmptyObjectSerializer(Class<EmptyObject> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(EmptyObject value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        // to maintain AF compatible format it is required to write {} instead of null
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  ...
  "data": {}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to write your own serializer you can use this approach of declaring type of field as *ObjectNode*:

```
private ObjectNode data;
```

You can set/initialize it like this:

```
data = new ObjectNode(JsonNodeFactory.instance)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom serializer for serializing Foo objects. Then in your custom FooSerializer implementation, you could check for a null bar value and serialize it as a default Bar instance. See https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/07/01/custom-serializer-jackson/ or http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization for some examples of how to create custom serializers.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unrelated to this, but if you define members as private on data class in Kotlin, then, Jackson serializer will produce empty json such as `{}`.

Comment: Just the problem I was having! Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

No. I don't see any way doing this. If you don't initialize your `Bar`, it'll be `null` inside the `JSON`.

Since you can't alter these classes, you can just check if the `Bar` inside the `Foo` is `null` and if it is, just initialize it and you'll get what you want.

```
Bar bar = foo.getBar();
if (bar == null) {
    foo.setBar(new Bar());
}
String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(foo);
```

The `json` will be the following:

```
{
    "bar" : {
        "fizz" : null, 
        "bang" : null 
    } 
}
```

Hope this helps.